# SQL Join two tables by two values which on of the values is inside of a longer text

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like to join two tables by two different values but one is inside of longer text. Could anyone help me with this!

items.item_dimensions = **250x300**

sales.variations = Size:**250x300** inches,Material:Print

```
SELECT *
FROM sales
LEFT JOIN items ON `items`.`id` = `sales`.`Listing id` AND `items`.`item_dimensions` = `sales`.`variations`
```

Comment: Don't do that. Store your data in a properly normalised format. This is going to cause horrendous maintenance and performance problems now and in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare using LIKE

```
SELECT *
FROM sales 
LEFT JOIN items ON `items`.`id` = `sales`.`Listing id` AND  `sales`.`variations` LIKE concat('%', `items`.`item_dimensions` , '%')
```